# Anonymous Functions Collections.sort java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, anonymous-function

Anyone offer a simple explanation as to how this list gets sorted and why the code in the anonymous function works to make the first item of the sorted list always be the last Lexicographical word at the top. I get that if a compareTo returns -1 0 and 1 by comparison but the code seems to imply that the parameters o1 and o2 might be compared at the same time...

```
List<String> allNames = new ArrayList<>();
allNames("Alfred");
allNames("Mary");
allNames("Hilda");
allNames("Zenda");
allNames("Thomas");
allNames("Isabel");



Collections.sort(allNames, new Comparator<String>() {
@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

if (o1.equals("Zenda") && !o2.equals("Zenda")){

return -1;

} else if (o2.equals("Zenda") && !o1.equals("Zenda")){

return 1 ;
}

return o1.compareTo(o2);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have put in special handling so that Zenda always sorts before anything else by checking the value and hard coding the -1 or 1 in the case where zenda is the first or second term respectively, then they delegate the remainder of the ordering to the regular string compareTo implementation.

Answer (score 1):

`Comparator.compare` is similar to `Comparable.compareTo`. They perform the same function, more or less, but what is different is the object doing the comparison. `compareTo` allows an object to compare itself to another object, while `compare` is used by a "third-party" object to compare two other objects.

The anonymous `Comparator` here is comparing two `String`s, `o1` and `o2`. If `o1` should come before `o2`, it returns `-1`. Else if `o2` should come before `o1`, `1` is returned.

What's special about your anonymous `Comparator` is that it ensures that `"Zenda"` is always considered to be first.

Comment: But does this mean that o1 and o2 could be the same object? As the code seems to be looking for an equals on the two arguments in the same conditional If statements?

Comment: They could be, sure. The first conditional checks if `o1` is "Zenda" and `o2` is NOT "Zenda", and the second conditional checks the opposite. If they were both "Zenda", for example, then the `else` condition occurs. `o1.compareTo(o2)` will return `0` if they are the same object, which tells the sorting method that the relative order of the two objects does not matter (because they are the same).

Comment: Not meaning to be picky but does anyone know the algorithm thats used so I can visualise the implementation. What is happening behind the scenes if easy to explain...